# Elasticsearch aggregation on array index or alternative solution

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have some documents in elasticsearch similar to these examples:

```
{
  "id": "<<some id>>",
  "list": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "id": "<<some id>>",
  "list": [
    "c",
    "a"
  ]
}
```

Such as the `list` can contain `a`, `b` and `c` in any order and not necessarily all of them. the order of the elements in the `list` matters.

I would like to run those bucket aggregations:

- how many documents contain `a` on any position
- how many document contains `a` in the **first** position

Would it be possible with the current document structure? Can I structure the document in a different way?

If it is not possible with the current structure, I was thinking to have something like:

```
{
  "id": "<<some id>>",
  "list": {
    "values": ["c", "a"],
    "ordered": {
      "0": "c",
      "1": "a"
    }
  } 
}
```

Or

```
{
  "id": "<<some id>>",
  "list": {
    "values": ["c", "a"],
    "ordered": {
      "a": 1,
      "c": 0
    }
  } 
}
```

With the latter, I would also be able to run aggregation like `a < c` and so on.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

there might be any better ways available but if you can store it like position followed by your key:

```
{
  "id": "<<some id>>",
  "list": [
    "1_a",
    "2_b",
    "3_c"
  ]
}
```

Another doc,

```
{
  "id": "<<some id>>",
  "list": [
    "1_c",
    "2_a"
  ]
}
```

then you can run normal aggregations over it and it would return something like:

```
1_a:1
2_a:1 ... etc
```

thereafter while processing you need to split by `_` else you can play around with scripts.